# # signs in ADO locates (Delphi XE5)

Tags: delphi, ado

With an TADOQuery.Locate that uses a list of fields and a VarArray of values, if one of the values contains a # sign, we get this exception:

```
'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.'
```

I've traced this down to ADODB which itself seems to be using # signs as delimiters.

Is there a way to escape #-signs so that the query doesn't fail?

*** EDIT 1  ***

I was wrong.  What causes this failure is a string that has a pound sign **and** a single quote.  The code shown below fails with error message noted above.

What *really* worries us is that when it fails running as an .exe outside the IDE, **there's no runtime exception**. We only see the exception when we're in the IDE. If our programmers hadn't happened to be using data that triggers this we never would have known that the .Locate returned FALSE because of a runtime error, not because a matching record was not found.

Code:

```
var 
  SearchArray: Variant;
begin
  SearchArray := VarArrayCreate([0,1], VarVariant);
  SearchArray[0] := 'T#more''wo';
  SearchArray[1] := 'One';

  ADOQuery.Locate('FieldName1;FieldName2', SearchArray, []);
```

Comment: In MS SQL Server `#` is prefix temporary tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see **Update**s below; I've found a work-around that's at least worth testing.

Even with Sql Server tables, the `#` shouldn't need to be escaped.

The following code works correctly in D7..XE8

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdoQuery1.Locate('country;class', VarArrayOf(['GB', Edit1.Text]), []);
end;
```

when `Edit1.Text` contains 'D#E', so I think your problem must lie elsewhere.  Try a minimalist project with just that code, after rebooting your machine.

**Update:** As noted in a comment, there is a problem with `.Locate` where the expression
passed to `GetFilterStr` (in ADODB.Pas) contains a `#` followed by a single quote.  To try and
work out a work-around for this, I've transplanted `GetFilterStr` into my code and have
been experimenting with using it to construct a recordset filter on my AdoQuery, as I noticed
that this is what `.Locate` does in the statement

```
FLookupCursor.Filter := LocateFilter;
```

The code I'm using for this, including my "corrected" version of `GetFilterStr`, is below.

What I haven't managed to figure out yet is how to avoid getting an exception on

```
    AdoQuery1.Recordset.Filter := S;
```

when the filter expression yields no records.

(Btw, for convenience, I'm doing this in D7, but using XE8's `GetFilterStr`, which is why I've had to comment out the reference to `ftFixedWideChar`)

```
function GetFilterStr(Field: TField; Value: Variant; Partial: Boolean = False): WideString;
// From XE8 Data.Win.ADODB
var
  Operator,
  FieldName,
  QuoteCh: WideString;
begin
  QuoteCh := '';
  Operator := '=';
  FieldName := Field.FieldName;
  if Pos(' ', FieldName) > 0 then
    FieldName := WideFormat('[%s]', [FieldName]);
  if VarIsNull(Value) or VarIsClear(Value) then
    Value := 'Null'
  else
    case Field.DataType of
      ftDate, ftTime, ftDateTime:
        QuoteCh := '#';
      ftString, ftFixedChar, ftWideString://, ftFixedWideChar:
        begin
          if Partial and (Value <> '') then
          begin
            Value := Value + '*';
            Operator := ' like ';     { Do not localize }
          end;
{.$define UseOriginal}
{$ifdef UseOriginal}
          if Pos('''', Value) > 0 then
            QuoteCh := '#' else
            QuoteCh := '''';
{$else}
          QuoteCh := '''';
          if Pos('''', Value) > 0 then begin
            QuoteCh := '';
            Value := QuotedStr(Value);
          end;
{$endif}
        end;
    end;
  Result := WideFormat('(%s%s%s%s%2:s)', [FieldName, Operator, QuoteCh, VarToWideStr(Value)]);
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateFilterExpr;
var
  S : String;
begin
  // clear any existing filter
  AdoQuery1.Recordset.Filter := adFilterNone;
  AdoQuery1.Refresh;

  if edFilter.Text = '' then Exit;

  S := GetFilterStr(AdoQuery1.FieldByName('Applicant'), edFilter.Text, cbPartialKey.Checked);
  //  Add the filter expr to Memo1 so we can inspect it
  Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
  try
    AdoQuery1.Recordset.Filter := S;
    AdoQuery1.Refresh;
  except
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FilterClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateFilterExpr;
end;
```

**Update 2:** Try the following:

- Copy Data.Win.ADODB.Pas to your project directory
- In it, replace GetFilterExpr by the version above, making sure that UseOriginal
  isn't DEFINEd, and that ftFixedWideChar is reinstated in the Case statement.
- Build and run your project

In XE8 at any rate, my testbed now correctly Locate()s a field ending with `'` or `#'`
(or containing either of them if `loPartialKey` is specified.  (I can't test in XE4/5
because my XE4 now says it's unlicenced since I upgraded to Win10 last week, thanks EMBA!)

I hestitate to call this a solution or even a work-around as yet, but it is at least worth testing.
I'm not sure whether I'd call the original version of `GetFilterExpr` bugged, because I'm not sure
what use-case its treatment of values containing quotes was intended to handle.

Comment: Could you try your test again with both a # and ' in the string? See my edits

Comment: I have, and the additional presence of a single quote indeed provokes the error message you describe.  The reason is that (in D7's ADODB.Pas, at least), the local function GetFilterStr returns a nonsensical value if its input happens to contain both a # and a single quote.  It doesn't look like it should be very difficult to work around but I'm a bit tied up right now - I'll take a look in the morning (12 hours from now).

Comment: Thanks, @MartynA. It's amazing to me that this bug should exist as recently as XE5.  

If there are any XE8 or XE 10 users out there, I'd love to know if this has been fixed in those versions.

Comment: I've just posted an update which adds what I've noticed so far.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Marty.  

The original code on my XE8 reads a bit differently than yours. It's:

 if Pos('''', Value) > 0 then
            QuoteCh := '#' else
            QuoteCh := '''';

which, if a Locate string contained a quote sign and pound sign (like  Some#More'Stuff), results in a filter like:

FieldName = #Some#More'Stuff#

The above is invalid and causes the failure..

Comment: I probably got the GetFilterExpr in a muddle - I'll check my XE8 ADODB.Pas