# How do you apply a Delphi ADOTable filter to a date data type

Tags: delphi, ms-access, filter, tadotable

in MS Access I am able to filter a date in a query like this: 
ex.

SignUpDate > #31/12/2013#

this will make the database only show records where SignUpDate is in 2014 or newer

How will I do this in delphi?

dmGym.tblMembers.filter := 'SignUpDate > ''#31/12/2013#''' doesn't seem to work

please help it wil be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try `dmGym.tblMembers.filter :=  'SignUpDate > #yyyy/mm/dd#'` (`2013/12/31`)

Comment: Thanks  it worked!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dmGym.tblMembers.filter := 'SignUpDate > #yyyy/mm/dd#' (2013/12/31)

-credit to kobik's comment

Answer (score 2):

**You can try :**

```
dmGym.tblMembers.Filter:='SignUpDate > 31/12/2013';
dmGym.tblMembers.Filtered:=True;
```

This will make the database only show records where SignUpDate is in 2014 or newer.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the `#`s, try

```
[...].Filter := '12/31/2013';  // this is for Sql Server and tested 
  //  for UK locale, for Access you may need to swap the dd and mm, 
  //and maybe even the yyyy as suggested by @kobik in a comment.
```

If you use a TDateTime field in a TAdoDataSet.Locate(), the function GetFilterStr plugs the `#` signs in for you (and makes a hash of it (spot the pun) when doing similar for string fields - see [# signs in ADO locates (Delphi XE5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751879/signs-in-ado-locates-delphi-xe5/32755259#32755259)).

But setting a simple filter on a TAdoTable seems to bypass ADODB.GetFilterStr and does a direct assignment to its recordset's Filter property, so I'm guessing that if the `#`s are needed, they must be plugged in by the ADO/MDac layer.

Comment: Thanks but kobik already answered my question and his way works

Comment: No probs - as I'd typed it I thought I might as well post it, esp as it goes a bit beyond your specific q.  I've edited it to acknowledge @kobik's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi stores the datetime as a real number.  Today is 05 June 2016 and the interger part of the DateTime is 42,526.  Date zero is the start of 1900.  You need to generate a variable called DateInt.

Var
  DateInt: integer
  Date1: TDate;
Begin
  DateInt := Trunc(Date1)

When you save a date, save DateInt in the BeforePost event handler.  This is an extra field, but filtering is now easy.  For example, your filter can now be

NewDateInt := Trunc(Date1);
Filter := ‘NewDate = DateInt’;